# regular expression extracting meta from html

Tags: python, regex

How to make the following regular expression:

```
<meta [^\>]*content\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1
```

if the name tag is dynamical?

The name tag is:

```
<meta *name="Generator"* ...
```

Solution:

```
re.compile(r""" <meta name=\"{0}\" [^\>]*content\s*=\s*(["\'])(.*?)\1""".format(meclue), re.I)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 'name tag' - do you mean the value of the name attribute, or the name of the tag ('meta' in your example)

Comment: the value of the name attribute.

Comment: That link is hilarious. And true.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to parse HTML with regex. It's a bad idea. Instead, use an HTML parser. lxml has a nice one:

```
import lxml.html

html_string = """<html>
<head>
  <meta name="firstname" />
  <meta name="secondname" />
  <meta someotherattribute="nonsense" />
</head>
<body>
  <p>Something in the body</p>
</body>
</html>"""

html_element = lxml.html.fromstring(html_string)
# get all the name attributes from all meta elements
meta_name_list = html_element.xpath("//meta/@name")
# print them out
for name in meta_name_list:
    print name
```

Output:

```
firstname
secondname
```

Comment: @JonClements I didn't realize he only wanted the name attribs. Updating.

Comment: there is some reasons why i want to use an regular expression, don't get away from the topic follow my question..

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex to match a meta tag with a name attribute, this should do it:

```
<meta name="[^"]*" />
```

I suspect from your regex you don't want to do this exactly. If this isn't what you need then please supply some example strings that you want the regex to match